# Limit CPU usage without Resource Governor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, resource-governor

We have an SQL Server 2008R2 Standard Edition with several databases belonging to different applications on a 16 core server.

One recently introduced application is regularly executing expensive queries that lead to 100% CPU usage. Of course the other applications are reporting performance issues.

The Resource Governor seems like a suitable tool to put the reins on the rogue application, unfortunately it is only available in the Enterprise Edition.

Since the other applications are rather simple, I tried to get the problem under control by reducing the "max degree of parallelism" of the instance, so that a single query can not bring down *everything*. While that succeeded in keeping the CPU load at 50%, it did surprisingly nothing to keep other applications from being bogged down.

Now we have decided to move the databases for the new application to a dedicated instance, but what would be the best configuration for this instance? Should I keep the MAXDOP-setting, use a CPU-affinity mask or is there another option to limit CPU usage that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM), which is a feature in Windows Server (not sure of minimum version, but definitely 2008 R2+).

This will allow you to control the amount of CPU used by a process, so if you hadn't already separated out the rogue application to its own SQL Server instance, you would have had do that anyway.

At that point you can set whatever `MAXDOP` you want, as the *process* will never exceed the maximum limits you set in WSRM.

---

Setting the CPU affinity mask is an option. You'd want to completely isolate the application onto its own set of cores to eliminate contention (note: watch your NUMA nodes). If you have those extra cores available, then go for it, but I'd prefer the WSRM solution because when that application is idle, *all* the CPUs can be used by other applications.

Answer (score 3):

If you're setting MAXDOP at half the cores, and other queries are still getting sidelined, you may be dealing with contention for memory or disk I/O. How much RAM is in the server, and how large is the application database?

Take a look at these perfmon counters when performance takes a nosedive, and you can get some idea if the server needs more memory or a faster disk subsystem:

**SQLServer:Buffer Manager**

- Page reads/sec
- Page life expectancy
- Buffer cache hit ratio

If Page reads/sec skyrockets, and the other two drop significantly, the troublesome query is probably trashing your buffer pool and causing a ton of disk I/O. You could then either work on tuning the query, or throw more hardware at it (more RAM, faster disks).

Comment: Good point, we have 12 GB and the database is 200GB. But our Buffer cache hit ratio is 100% and always stays very high. I also do not see unusually high I/O. But I will remember to limit the maximum memory for the new dedicated instance.