# MSSQL Server Resource Governance alternative

Tags: sql-server, cpu, standard-edition, enterprise-edition, resource-governor

I've been looking into solutions for managing CPU sharing over multiple apps accessing the same SQL server database engine.I found that Resource Governance is one perfect way for me to define those rules.

Just after completing my researches and when trying to deploy the solution to the production server, I'm shocked to know that Resource Governance is only available for the Enterprise edition where I actually have the Standard Edition.

Any alternative solutions for SQL Standard Edition ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51887/limit-cpu-usage-without-resource-governor) Stackexchange thread talks about `Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM)` to manage CPU's, its a windows server feature please see if that helps.

Comment: Shanky, I thought that WSRM is no more, as of Win 2016...?

Comment: WSRM is not going to do what resource governor does and has been retired. RG works inside of SQL Server on the server side, WSRM doesn't work on the server side, it treats the entire instance, not individual work groups, as the entity. Forget WSRM or jobs as that's not going to fit the OPs requirements. Upgrading the Enterprise Edition, however, will.

Comment: @Shanky thanks, but the solution proposed on that thread suggests moving the heavy-load app to its own SQL instance, which gets me wondering how that app's instance would be able to read from the same tables of the other applications. Have an idea?

Comment: @HasanBaidoun You can replicate the table to new instance or even use AG if "reading" is only the thing you want to do. If writing is also what you need replication with updateable subscription can also be used. Well not full proof but you can give it a try. Or else upgrade to Ent edition.